# Java program to use three methods together and call each at a time

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to create a Java program to prompt the user to enter a DNA sequence and
use validate() method. Then, after the DNA is validated, I wanted to get the length of my validated DNA
sequence using another getLength() method. Then, I want to use count() method to count T and A bases in my
validated DNA sequence, calculate the percentage of each. This is what I got so far. I am not getting the result. I can get the DNA but the length and TAcount is not giving result. Can somebody help?

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class dnaseq
{


   // using first method validate() - prompt the user for the DNA and confirms it is DNA seq  //
   public static void Validate(String[] args)
   {


    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter DNA: ");
    String dna = user_input.next();


    for (int i=0; i < dna.length(); i++){

        char base=dna.charAt(i);


        if (base !='T' && base !='A' && base !='C' && base !='G'){
        System.out.println ("Wrong input!");
    }

    else { 
        System.out.println ( dna);

    }}}

    //After getting the dna sequence, use getLength() to get the length of dna seq//
    public int getLength(){
        int length=0;
        int n=0;

         for(int j = 0; j < dna.length(); j++){
             char base=dna.charAt(j);


             if (base !='T' && base !='A' && base !='C' && base !='G'){
            System.out.println (+n);

         }
    return n;}

    //use TAcount to get % of T and A bases in your DNA seq above// 
    static double TAcount( double count) {
              double count = 0.0;

               for(int k = 0; k < dna.length(); k++){
                   char base=dna.charAt(k);
                      if (base !='T'){
                                count = count + 1.0;} 
                        if (base !='A'){ 
                                 count = count + 1.0;}
                          }
                        if (dna.length()> 0){
                            T_base = dna.TAcount('T');
                            A_base = dna.GTcount('A');
                            T_percent = G_base / dna.length() *100;
                            A_percent = T_base / dna.length() *100;
                        }




                      System.out.println(T_percent);
                      System.out.println(A_percent);

    }
```

Comment: You need to be specific about what you need help with. Are you getting errors (list the exact error and where they occur), is the output not what you expect (give example input and the expected output and say what you are actually getting).

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: The first method Validate worked fine. I am stuck at getlength() to get the length of my DNA and TAcount() methods to get count and % of T and A in my DNA

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, good practice in Java is to capitalize all class names - and you should work on your formatting. Good formatting practices help us better understand what you've written and it also helps you understand where things are out of place (most of the time).

Answer (score 1):

You declared **TAcount** method inside **getLength** method. **TAcount** accept parameter **count*** and you declared another variable with same name inside the method. `String dna = user_input.next();` declared inside **Validate** and you try to access the **DNA** in different method. Variable declared inside the method id known as **Local Variable** and is not acceesible by other method. Where is **seg**? You are trying to access that variable and I didnt see you declare it anywhere. Try to fix this and let us know where you stuck.

And what is this?

```
T_base = dna.TAcount('T');
A_base = dna.GTcount('A');
T_percent = G_base / dna.length() *100;
A_percent = T_base / dna.length() *100;
```

Variable without data types.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code.

a) Why do you need a separate getLength() method when you are already validating the DNA sequence? Even if you need to know the length of the DNA sequence, you are already storing it in a String object, so you can use the String.length() method.

b) You havent declared the string object dna as a global variable, you will not be able to access it inside TAcount().

c) The for-loop inside TAcount() needs to be revised thoroughly. You are also trying to make a recursive call using chars! And you havent defined GTcount().

d) Since you are already iterating in the validation method, why dont you store the counter of T's and A's separately there itself? It will help in avoiding iterating it again.